# How to resuse train information in SVM classifier

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using opencv SVM classifier for classifying digits and alphabets. (Number of features  = 20000, length of each feature vector = 125, number of classes 36).

When I run my program, the following function (training) is taking a lot of time

```
svmob.train_auto(m_features, m_labels, cv::Mat(), cv::Mat(), m_params, 10);
```

Is there any way to store output of above function and use it in the next run of the program ?

So that I can avoid training time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, just save the trained model:

```
svmob.train_auto(m_features, m_labels, cv::Mat(), cv::Mat(), m_params, 10);
svmob.save("svmob.yml.gz"); // zipping saves 3/4 space.
```

later, instead of re-training, read it back in:

```
SVM svmob;
svmob.load("svmob.yml.gz");
svmob.predict(...);
```

Comment: what is  .yml extension ?

Comment: yaml. but you can use xml, too. (yaml is just a bit shorter)